# Xamarin Authentifiication Facebook & google with IdentityModel.OidcClient not working

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, oauth-2.0

**can't use authentifiication Facebook & google in OidcClient :**

- Xamarin Forms v 3.4.0.1008975
- IdentityModel.OidcClient v 3.12

i try to use [IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples/tree/master/XamarinForms)
with facebook and google but not working always iv the same Error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Error loading discovery document: Error connecting to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?/.well-known/openid-configuration: Bad Request
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the actual discovery document url is https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration

Comment: no is not url is Error my url is https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?

Comment: It is quite clear from the error that the url there is failing. It is trying to access a discovery document there. Maybe in your authority url you have set the authorization endpoint instead of the base url as you should.